# AutoDesk Forge: what should I fill in :owner when I want to get/put servicelimits

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I try to use this service to read and change the service limits. However, whatever I try to fill for owner, it is giving me a 403 message. Authentication was not problem, other requests work. I try to use the client id, but that was not working. It is the only place where I see the usage of owner in Autodesk Forge.

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/servicelimits/:owner

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be string "me". See the tests in our SDK which you can take as an example.

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-design.automation/blob/39861656ee879f1a53dce49832a9ae99fbd77372/tests/e2e/recordings/ServiceLimits_Get.json#L70

Comment: "me" works fine for me, would be useful to add this to the documentation. Unfortunately it is not possible to increase limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB, although the documentation is stating so. Our IFC export from Revit is regularly failing because of memory problems. I hoped setting this parameter would have solved the problem.

Comment: If the memory consumption problem happens during a run of the Revit when a workitem is in process, then limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB will not help you. I would know more in case you would be able to give me more info from the Workitem report.

Comment: This is what the log is saying. In another case is was suggested that this could be a memory problem. It always fails with the IFC export step: Exporting ifc...
IFC exported
Failure 0:  Severity: Error There has been an unrecoverable error during export.  Export will now be aborted.
Attempting to continue.
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.   at IFCTransaction.{dtor}(IFCTransaction* )

Comment: at DiscardedObjectsHospice.addOne<class IFCTransaction>(DiscardedObjectsHospice* , IFCTransaction* pMostlyDead)
   at Autodesk.Revit.Proxy.DB.IFC.IFCTransactionProxy.ReleaseUnmanagedResources(Boolean disposing)
   at Autodesk.Revit.Proxy.DB.IFC.IFCTransactionProxy.Dispose(Boolean A_0)
End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code -1073741819 which indicates an error.
End script phase.
Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
Job finished with result FailedExecution

Comment: @Nomis23, are you exporting big Revit model? If so, there might be some out of memory error. We did some improvement on memory issue on Design Automation for Revit and we are going to deploy more improvements soon. Hope it would help. 
If you keep seeing the errors even for small-size Revit models, we will need your dataset to reproduce and investigate then.

Comment: @EmmaZhu: it is not so big to my opinion, maybe 200 MB maximum, but also sometimes much smaller. It is not a big issue to share the model and part of the code, if we can do it safely.

Comment: @Nomis23, we deployed improvements on memory yesterday. I am not sure your ifc case will be solved by this improvement, but please try! If it still doesn't work, yes, we need the model and addin code to reproduce and investigate. See also [Requesting support for failed WorkItems](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/troubleshooting/). To safe share the dataset, please contact: forge.help@autodesk.com

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `:owner` refers to the "Forge app name" which is typically the Forge Client ID (unless you change it to something else via the https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/forgeapps-id-PATCH endpoint).